# Is Vladimir Putin surrounded by yes-men?

Tags: russian-federation, government, vladimir-putin

#### Context

In general, authoritarian leaders who have been in power for a long time are at risk of being misinformed: their advisors may be tempted to hide the bad news by fear of being blamed for them, they might embellish the truth to stay in the leader's good graces. By definition, authoritarian leaders tend not to tolerate contradiction and surround themselves with people who think like them. [Confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias) and a lack of diverse perspectives would obviously hinder their ability to get an objective and complete picture of the situation.

Putin's government appears to show signs of this problem:

- For example, the video of [Putin asking his officials to sign off his decision](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/feb/21/putin-angry-spectacle-amounts-to-declaration-war-ukraine), including [the scolding of his intelligence chief](https://www.theguardian.com/world/video/2022/feb/22/speak-plainly-putin-tense-exchange-spy-chief-ukraine-video), shows a inflexible leader probably feared by his officials.
- There are clear indications that the Russian army was not well prepared, in particular suffering [egregious logistics issues](https://ecfr.eu/article/combined-farces-russias-early-military-failures-in-ukraine/). This is the kind of issue which is fairly easy to anticipate, so presumably the state of preparedness of the army was overestimated when the decision to invade was made.
- The resistance of the Ukrainian army and the Ukrainian population in general was drastically underestimated by Moscow. Putin even [addressed the Ukrainian troops, asking them to overthrow their government](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHVX2sUFdPk). This looks like a fairly serious misunderstanding of the general state of mind in Ukraine, consistent with the Russian government believing their own propaganda instead of relying on objective intelligence reports.

Beyond Putin himself, there seems to be a culture of non-transparency and fabricating "alternative facts" at the top of the Russian government which may affect how the government and the army function: if at every level in a hierarchy people tell their boss what they *want* to hear instead of what they *need* to hear, it can lead to vast discrepancies between the situation as observed at the bottom of the hierarchy and as reported at the top.

#### Question

- Is there evidence that the Russian government decision process is systematically biased by a culture of non-transparency and repression of diverging opinions?

---

Edit: a couple weeks later, the US and the EU were making remarks along the same lines as my question, e.g. [Why is GCHQ saying Putin has been misinformed about Ukraine war?](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/mar/31/why-is-gchq-saying-putin-has-been-misinformed-about-ukraine-war), [Putin misled by 'yes men' in military afraid to tell him the truth](https://www.rte.ie/news/world/2022/0330/1289431-putin-russia-ukraine/).

Comment: How would we know?  And by what objective measure would you define a "yes man"?  The answer is probably yes, from people inclined to believe the worse of Putin (me).  But you could equally well point to "impressive credentials" of his close associates to state this wasn't the case.  Also, there is a subtle difference between a yes man clique and a [group think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupthink) situation.  I'd say the Bush administration, when it invaded Iraq in 03 was group thinking, not yes men.  But from the outside, the outcome is much the same.  VTC, not answerable.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica my title question is perhaps too simplified. the non-simplified question is about how the Russian government actually works in general, what is their culture. For example, do officials get punished when they voice different opinions or report true but unpleasant news? Do competent people get sidelined if they are perceived as reluctant to embellish things? Do people get rewarded just for systematically siding with the boss? I'm aware that the question may not be easy to answer, but I think it's reasonably objective.

Comment: This questions *needs more focus* because it is clearly asking two different questions.

Comment: Honestly the question seems just like an occasion for us to list reasons to believe how corrupt, coercive and unpleasant Putin's regime is.  Which could very well be true, but not objectively provable from the information we have access to.  From all indications, no one really knows what drove Putin to take this decision *despite the risks*.  The yes man hypothesis has traction, in fact FSB agents are reportedly under arrest for just this reason.  But everyone is reading tea leaves and insisting that this is an important question does not make it answerable.

Comment: [US intelligence agencies make understanding Vladimir Putin's state of mind a top priority](https://www.cnn.com/2022/03/01/politics/us-intelligence-putin-state-of-mind/index.html) was posted here before: we don't know.

Comment: In case anybody is interested, I asked a [question on meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6211/23571) about this question.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Let's give the question a chance, shall we? That's the only way to be sure, to quote from *Aliens*. :)

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica Could you please take a look at it now? I adjusted the focus button on the Q. :)

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I will provide an outline of an A, not an A *per se* (bc the Q is still closed). I compare the observed facts in Putin's inner circle to those in a non-"yes man" control group (Biden's inner circle). I ask and will answer these questions: What fraction of the inner circle is turned over? Of, these, what fraction loses job and/or freedom? How often do we observe the inner circle messages different from those of the leader? Etc. The margins of this comment are too small for an answer with refs. But this is an outline of a viable answer that's fit to print. So pls VTR!

Comment: You might want to ask the broader question that pertains to all leaders.  After all, what leader would surround themself with opponents?

Comment: @BeginnerBiker Not necessarily opponents, but independent thinkers who often argue with each other, and are therefore be definition not "yes men". Examples of JFK, Obama, Biden come to mind as those who did not surround themselves by "yes men". Note that Obama appointed Hillary Clinton to his cabinet, his former rather **bitter** opponent in the presidential primary elections. Did Putin appoint Kasparov, Navalny, or any one of his many other **bitter** opponents to his cabinet? Does he even let them in? Perhaps to sit at his long table?

Comment: "systematically biased by a culture of non-transparency and repression of diverging opinions" sounds like a very low bar. Any country's government is probably "systematically biased" by a culture of non-transparency. It's the actual strength of this effect that matters.

Comment: @alamar I would argue that, in democratic countries, it would not be possible to deny some unpleasant reality completely, due to free media and political opposition. In Russia both are muzzled and some truths are even made illegal, so simply addressing some real issue might at least make someone suspect, if not send them to prison. You're right that it's a matter of degree, but in this sense one can consider that there is particularly strong culture of non-transparency in Russia.

Comment: @Erwan Russian politics are far less violent than one may infer from the Western media. That girl who waved a sign in front of prime time news got a $250 fine. I don't think anybody went to jail yet over the new martial law. Whereas in the West, it's not hard to get cancelled on Twitter and then get fired.

Comment: @alamar: this is ridiculous: a person simply calling the Ukraine war a war can legally be sent to jail. Only the threat of jail is already a very high level of violence compared to just being forbidden on twitter. Additionally there is huge difference when a state makes something officially illegal, and the general sentiment about something in a particular population.

Comment: @Erwan I wonder if there are any confirmed cases of prosecution for "simply" calling conflict in Ukraine a war. I think that's the guideline that the opposition press thought out (before running outside the country with "no to the war" cries)

Comment: @alamar whether actual prosecutions or not, the threat is sufficient to coerce most people to shut up. At the army/government level, I assume that the people in charge have to maintain the fable that they are just doing a "peacekeeping mission", which can make it hard to communicate properly about the real situation. There is evidence that many Russian soldiers sent in Ukraine had no idea they were going to war, causing terrible moral and huge losses. It was also told that Putin himself wasn't made aware that young conscripts were sent to Ukraine. In any case, this cannot be efficient.

Comment: "Most people" are completely irrelevant when we are discussing Putin's inner circle. In fact, the best advice for the "most people" during the conflict is to keep their mouth shut. All the other options, from participating in state propaganda to disseminating adversarial propaganda, are worse.

Comment: @Timur ... Hillary Clinton belongs to the Democratic party and as such is cut from the same ideological cloth, namely, the established, capitalist ruling class off the USA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's rather difficult to know what goes behind closed doors in the Kremlin, but he is surrounded by the TV version of yesmen given the public dress down he [gave](https://english.elpais.com/opinion/2022-02-23/the-russian-spy-boss-humiliated-by-putin.html) to the SVR chief recently, whom looked very  eager to revise every sentence he had just uttered, to please Putin.

What has been more easily seen/measured from the outside [is that](https://ecfr.eu/article/commentary_putins_incredible_shrinking_circle_7099/) in 2016-2018 Putin did a "soft purge" moving to less consequential positions a number of his "old guard" confidants, including e.g. Sergei Ivanov, whom once (1999) Putin had declared to be his most trusted adviser. The guy (Vaino) whom replaced Ivanov was someone who literally had carried Putin's umbrella on a number of occasions.

On the other hand, Putin is [somewhat famous](https://www.economist.com/europe/2019/06/22/the-improbable-careers-of-vladimir-putins-bodyguards) for promoting former bodyguards to positions of power that often enough exceed their competencies, like region governors and ministers. From this it's speculated that he values loyalty above much else, although they are also easily dismissed from such posts, sometimes soon (months) after such high-level appointments. Perhaps he takes "sink or swim" approach.

Comment: I would also note that Putin uses cellphones/computers and has Internet access, so it's not like the old days when the glorious leader could've lived in complete isolation from the open media.

Answer (score 2):

Differently, **V.Putin may be the yes man himself**.

Or at least Yevgeny Prigozhin thinks so. As [Meduza](https://meduza.io/feature/2023/06/23/rossiyskaya-armiya-otstupaet-minoborony-obmanyvaet-putina-ukraina-i-nato-ne-sobiralis-napadat-na-rossiyu) writes,

*the war was needed for the oligarchs, the clan that actually controls Russia now.  These people don't think about anyone but themselves.  The oligarchs wanted to make Viktor Medvedchuk the president of Ukraine, who specially returned to Kyiv for this.  Our holy war with those who offend the Russian people has turned into racketeering.*